# Count de consulta nativa não retorna o mesmo tipo no SQL Server e H2

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Olá,

Tenho uma consulta nativa que faz um simples `count` de registros de uma tabela:

```
public Long contar() {
    String sql "SELECT count(*) FROM Order";
    Query query = query.createNativeQuery(sql);
    // return...
}
```

No sistema, usamos em produção o SQL Server e para os testes de integração usamos o banco de dados H2.

Porém, aparentemente o Hibernate não tem um padrão do tipo de dado retornado do `count` nativo entre estes dois bancos. No H2 é retornado um `BigInteger` e no Sql Server é retornado um `Integer`. Em consultas usando JPQL, o tipo retornado é sempre `Long`, independente do banco de dados.

Assim, se tento no H2:

```
return ((Integer) query.getSingleResult()).longValue();
```

Recebo:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Se tento usar o `BigInteger`, O H2 aceita e os testes passam. Mas ao tentar isto no Sql Server:

```
return ((BigInteger) query.getSingleResult()).longValue();
```

Recebo o erro:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.math.BigInteger

Tentei usar Long:

```
return (Long) query.getSingleResult();
```

Mas recebo o erro (como esperado):

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Assim, qual seria a forma correta de converter o valor do contador para que funcione nos dois bancos de dados?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lembrei que tive este problema em um software no qual já trabalhei, que ao invés de H2 usava HsqlDB, e consultei meus ex-colegas para lembrar da solução.

É possível usar `Number` e converter o resultado para `Long`:

```
return ((Number) query.getSingleResult()).longValue();
```